# Exporting an eclipse project as gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I have been trying to export my eclipse project as a gradle build file to use it with Android Studio but I can't seem to make it work correctly.
When I click "Finish" nothing happens. If I repeatedly click it, I can see a progress bar that shows for a millisecond and then vanishes.

My ADT is version 22.3 (which is the latest) and I have tried all of the solutions I found on google as well.

Similar questions can be found here:
Eclipse Gradle export of Android project does nothing
Cannot generate gradle.build files from Eclipse

As you can see, there is not really a solid solution for this problem, but people wrote they created it manually. I don't know how to do so though.

Is there any solution for this problem that I haven't heard of? If not, how can I create the file manually?

Comment: Try creating a new empty project, then exporting it. If that works, then there is something about your real project that is confusing the export process. If that fails, then there is something about your environment that is a problem.

Comment: Check the folder which Eclipse shows as root folder to your project, if it's the correct one. In my situation that was the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh wow. I just found out it is a problem with my project... x.x The libraries and a blank project export as they should. Any ideas what could cause it? I read before that warnings prevented it from exporting... but I have already 'suppressed' them all.

Comment: I have only exported simple projects, so I do not know exactly what might trigger your problem. You mention libraries, and I definitely have not tried exporting an Eclipse project that had references to library projects. Perhaps add a library project to your new blank project, and see if that affects whether it can be exported. If you do not get a solid answer here after ~24 hours, you might try the `adt-dev` Google Group.

Comment: @CommonsWare You were spot on! I tried unlinking the libraries from my project and it works now! Now I only got to figure out how to re-link them on android studio. Thanks! Would you please reply it as an answer so I can select it as best answer? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, the current edition of the export-to-Gradle support in Eclipse cannot handle a project that is attached to an Android library project. In that case, you would need to (temporarily) detach the Android library project, export the main project, then modify `build.gradle` to use the library project ([manually](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library) or via Android Studio).

Comment: please explain detaching the Android library project and modifying build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the black magic spell! Without stackoverflow, we would be already doomed long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Generating build.gradle files **FIRST FOR ALL of the projects in my dependencies ONE AFTER ANOTHER** worked for me.

I generated build.gradle (with export wizrd for facebook, play and whatever other projects I imported and used in my project).

Answer (score 0):

For not trivial Android project you should do it manually.

For the latest `build.gradle` template for classic Android project check [gh.c/N/n-1/b/m/o.n.e.e.g/docs/android/build.gradle](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle).

You can continue to develop in Eclipse with ADT and run Gradle build using [Nodeclipse/Enide Gradle for Eclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle)
([marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle))

Some screenshots for Gradle for Eclipse:

[image]

[image]