# Make Gradle use Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'd like to make Gradle use Eclipse project dependencies. Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19907397/581205), I don't want to do any export as I don't want to hunt down problems due to forgetting to re-export after a change. And unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14615872/581205), I don't want to integrate Gradle into Eclipse at all, as I'm satisfied with how my Eclipse works (it's much faster than a Gradle build) and I'm also afraid that my Eclipse 3.7.2 may be too old for such games.

Ideally, I'd like something like

```
dependencies {
    compile allFilesFromEclipse()
}
```

Actually, getting the JARs would suffice.

What I've tried: Just some light googling. I could imagine parsing the `.classpath` file myself, but it's not done in 5 minutes, so I'm asking if there's an existing solution.

Comment: In my company we did something like what you are describing some years ago. (Reading the MANIFEST.MF and generating a build.gradle from it). However, it was a long and painful development and I would not recommend it. (By long I mean weeks). Besides, since it is not standard, and it was done by a team that is not in the company anymore, it has become as a kind of legacy code, very difficult to maintain....

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you won't find much help. It is not obvious what problem you want to solve here. Most developers prefer to base their build on a build tools rather than expect that they will replicated an IDE setup everywhere.

As for Eclipse 3.7.2: I am not sure why you want to stick with that but `gradle eclipse` generates files that work with this version.

Comment: *"replicated an IDE setup everywhere"* - How is using `.classpath` different from using `build.gradle`? All I want is to use the dependencies as already written in a file instead of writing them anew and keeping them in sync. ### There's a [very good reason](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html) not to upgrade. At least for me. ### `gradle eclipse` could generate files I already have from files I don't have. ### And yes, for projects I'm currently working on, I have a full `build.gradle`, my question concerns other projects where I don't want invest much time.